# Error when inserting data in temporary table (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a temporary table and add information from another table into it. However I keep getting the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT course_name, ins_name FROM courses where
>   course_name='ACCA'' at line 2'

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (course, ins) 
  SELECT course_name, ins_name
  FROM courses
  where course_name = 'ACCA'
```

Comment: I believe the syntax is SELECT ... INTO #Table FROM ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create the temp table first

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
 IF NOT EXISTS your_table  AS (SELECT course_name, ins_name
             FROM courses 
             where course_name='ACCA');
```

Answer (score 1):

your syntax is fine. However in order to use it you must first create table `#TempTable`.

More details [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: i think in this case the error will be `Table doesn't exist `